# Why GuildAuditLogsEntry.target is null?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I try to make a Discord bot to show me who moved an user from voice channel and i got the name of the admin who did the action but GuildAuditLogsEntry.target  is null. Its bad cause i need the name of the user who was moved also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to keep this short.
GuildAudits are usually inaccurate, and have alot of missing data, so I wouldn't suggest using it.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this ??

Comment: Unless the user is moved using the bot (you can log actions made with the bot), then no. Please flag this as a correct answer :)